# Bind @param in a Jpa repository native query inside single quotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for a way to bind a given param in a native query where the value has to be inside single quotations, like so:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = " SELECT c.ID " +
               " FROM table1 clh " +
               " LEFT JOIN table2 nks " +
               " on clh.SERIAL = nks.SERIAL_REF " +
               " WHERE clh.CREATED_DATE >= :now - interval ':timeThreshold' HOUR " +
               " AND nks.SERIAL_REF IS NULL" , nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> getIdsWithoutAnswer (@Param("timeThreshold") Integer timeThreshold, @Param("now") LocalDateTime now);
```

However, when I try to run this, it results in hibernate not being able to bind the timeThreshold value as it is provided inside the single quotations ''.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Oracle) ?

Comment: Try to remove the quotes. But I'm even not sure if you can have bind variables there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen im using Oracle in this case.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have tried to remove the singe quotes, but then it complains about not being a valid syntax when attempting to run the query. I have also attempted to pass it as a string instead, both with and without the single quotations; didnt work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having with your native Oracle query has to do with trying to bind a value to an interval literal.  You can't do that.  Instead, use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL()` function:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(value = " SELECT c.ID " +
               " FROM table1 clh " +
               " LEFT JOIN table2 nks " +
               " on clh.SERIAL = nks.SERIAL_REF " +
               " WHERE clh.CREATED_DATE >= :now - numtodsinterval(:timeThreshold, 'hour') " +
               " AND nks.SERIAL_REF IS NULL" , nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> getIdsWithoutAnswer (@Param("timeThreshold") Integer timeThreshold, @Param("now") LocalDateTime now);
```

Comment: Ah, I see - that appeard to do the trick; thanks.

I also realized that another way to go about it was to pre-determine the date by subtracting the hour threshold from a LocalDateTime property and then simply pass the date to be compared with.